# Is the Spanner's CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() guaranteed to never go backwards?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

My application needs a sorted column of timestamp that is monotonically increasing. I can't use commit timestamp as I cannot store future timestamps there.

Instead, I am looking at storing TIMESTAMP_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() + INTERVAL $delay SECOND) in the sorted column. [[Current Timestamps Doc]](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/functions-and-operators#current_timestamp)

I wanted to know if I can rely on CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() to be monotonically increasing?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() doesn't guarantee monotonically increasing timestamps.

commit_timestamp functionality relies on [TrueTime](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/true-time-external-consistency) to generate monotonically increasing timestamps. But It can't hold true if you are storing future timestamps.